# SQL Server Compact: Left Join returns only one row FOR MOST entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a web app in asp.net and I am using the SQL provided by VS Community 2015 to create and manage the DB.

At some point, I want to return all entries in one table,joining it with another table which **can have entirely empty records**. This latter table is populated with data entered by the users as they interact with the website.

However, my stored procedure only fetches one of the four rows I want it to fetch FOR MOST of my records. While I was testing my code I got into the habit of using only one profile, for which it works as expected. This is the weird part for me... Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

```
create proc UserProfile
@email varchar(100)
as
begin
select * from TabelNume where email = @email
declare @moduleID int
declare @participantID int
select @moduleID = Session_Fk from TabelNume where email=@email
select @participantID = id from TabelNume where email=@email
select * from Modules where Id = @moduleID;
select * from Meetings left outer join Scales on Meetings.Id = Scales.Meeting_FK 
    where Meetings.Module_FK = @moduleID and (Participants_FK = @participantID or Participants_FK is null)
end
```

So here, when I run `spUserProfile 'unu@unu.com'` it retrieves 4 rows for my join.

However, when I run `spUserProfile 'doi@doi.com'` it only fetches 1 row. This row is the last entry with the `Meetings.Module_FK` as specified in the sp. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The SQL Server that comes with VS Community 2015 is most likely **not** SQL Server Compact (CE) - that's being deprecated. It most likely is SQL Server **LocalDB** (a programmer's version of Express)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the conditions in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause.  Here is your query:

```
select *
from Meetings left outer join
     Scales
     on Meetings.Id = Scales.Meeting_FK 
where Meetings.Module_FK = @moduleID and
       (Participants_FK = @participantID or Participants_FK is null)
```

And this is what it should be:

```
select *
from Meetings left outer join
     Scales
     on Meetings.Id = Scales.Meeting_FK and
        Participants_FK = @participantID
where Meetings.Module_FK = @moduleID;
```

Why aren't they equivalent?  Well, this is a little hard to explain.  The first version seems like it should do what you want.  But, the problem is when a meeting has any participant who is not the one you care about.  Then, your `where` clause fails.  The `Participants_FK = @participantID` fails because the participants don't match.  The `Participants_FK is null` fails because the column always has a value -- just the non-matching ones.

So, your query gets either Meetings with no participants or Meetings with your participant id; it filters out everything else.

Finally, if you only want information about `Meetings`, then you should probably use `EXISTS` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, it solved my issue. I need a left join because if the value is null I dynamically change the behavior of a page. I appreciate the explanation as well, it's informative! I will mark the answer as soon as I am allowed.